# How do i make side-nav's icon responsive and fully match with the width of my side-nav?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is my `side-nav` code, am using the default side nav of angular material. Am very confused right now can u guy explain to me how to do it. PS am new to angular.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="false"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false"
  >
    <mat-toolbar>
      <button class="button1" type="button">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-nav-list>
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>bar_chart</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>home_work</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>receipt_long</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>app_settings_alt</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"
      >
        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content
></mat-sidenav-container>
```